# DataAdapter.SelectCommand and SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql

I have desktop application with an export function.

The export-columns are in a config-file. Currently the non-included columns are removed from the dataset after db retrieval.

The db retrieval part for the export is now something like:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM WHATEVER WHERE ID=:ID";

using (var cmd = ConFactory.CreateOracleCommand())
{
      cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = id;
      cmd.CommandText = sql;

      using (var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
      {
          dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
          dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
      }
      ...
}
```

However, this is quite wasteful when typically only one or two out of many hundreds of columns are configured for export.

So for efficiency I want to pass the columns specified in the config file to the method and rewrite the sql to something like this:

```
// columns is List<string>
string sColumns = string.Join(",", columns);

var sql = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM WHATEVER WHERE ID=:ID", sColumns);
```

But in case someone types something bad into the config-file, are there any problems with using this approach with dataAdapter.SelectCommand & Fill? Is it safe for SQL injection? I haven't found any documentation about it.

Does it help that all blanks " " has been removed from the strings in Columns-list?

Comment: There's a *lot* of documentation about ADO.NET commands. Safety comes from the use of parameterized queries, not the use of OracleCommand itself. If you add unsanitized strings, you expose yourself to SQL injection. Why are you using data adapters though, especially if you want the columns to change at runtime? Why not use an ORM like EF and only load the data you want in the shape you want with a `.Select()` ?

Comment: If you want to *export* data, using a DataTable simply wastes memory by loading everything in RAM before you can process the first row. You could use `cmd.ExecuteReader()` and export the rows as they arrive. Libraries like `CsvHelper` or EppPlus accept readers as inputs to generate CSV or Excel files.

Comment: Well... `SELECT X;DROP TABLE WHATEVER; FROM WHATEVER...`... I hope you got the point already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, but not using EF because this is not a greenfield app. Was just looking for a way to optimize what is already there for a quick win without changing too much.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, I get the point, hence the question. But as I wrote, for each configured column all whitespace is removed. So that example would yield the sql "SELECT X;DROPTABLEWHATEVER; FROM WHATEVER".

Comment: What I could probably also do is an initial select * from the table without any data, then keep all the column names and and throw a "configuartion exception" if any configured column does not exactly match exactly that of what is in the database before execute the sql.

Comment: @Stokke then remove the adapter entirely. You can load a DataTable from a reader with `DataTable.Load(reader)`. Better yet remove the DataTable itself and actually export the data as needed

Comment: @Stokke if the column names don't contain table aliases you could use a regex to check that all characters are in the expected range, eg `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$` would match alphanumeric-only names. You'd still have to check against the actual column names to discover mistakes before the job starts

Comment: It's not safe by default. At least you should use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to sanitize your column names. Of course, in each DBMS you need to act in your own way.